# CRM Async Delete

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

When i try execute async delete that I get error

```
    System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1: 'Request of type 'Delete' can not be executed in async'
```

How to resolve this problem, i need in async deleting

```
  var req = new DeleteRequest()
  {
    Target = new EntityReference(XrmEntityNames.Solution, solutionId)
  };
  ExecuteAsyncRequest asyncReq = new ExecuteAsyncRequest()
  {
    Request = req
  };
  sdkSvc.Execute(asyncReq);
```

Comment: We have no idea how `Execute()` works. Read the docs, maybe?

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executeasyncrequest.request?view=dataverse-sdk-latest#microsoft-xrm-sdk-messages-executeasyncrequest-request) "Currently this only supports the ImportSolutionRequest message"